# How can i add min and max range horizontal line in angular-chart.js

Tags: chart.js, angular-chart

I am using http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

I want to show a horizontal line in the graph where i can indicate this is Max value and this is Min value.

How can i add min and max range horizontal line?

Answer (score 1):

angular-chart.js uses Chart.js and there is annotation plugin [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) which may do what you want.

Comment: Thankyou Paul but i want to show 2 bars. Any idea for same.

Comment: The **annotations** setting takes an array. So you should be able to define a second one here. (I haven't tried this!). Something like: {annotation: {annotations: [{type: 'line', value: 100}, {type: 'line', value: 200}] }}

Comment: Thanks Paul. It really helps me alot.
For double lines you have to use different "drawTime" name and "id" name.

Comment: This is working example for same [Visit Demo] https://codepen.io/ambujkhanna/pen/dRbLow?editors=0110